# mongoDB run queries just like as SQL !

Tags: c#, linq, performance, mongodb

```
    public IQueryable<T> GetRecords<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, int from, int first) where T : class, new()
    {
        first = first == 0 ? 30 : first;
        return _db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName).Linq().Where(expression).Skip(from).Take(first);
    }
    var x = GetRecords<Event>(p => true, 0, 12222);
    string eventJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(x);
```

this function get the data from mongoDB.

```
    SqlDataReader dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader("Select Top(12222)* From NewsFeed");
    string eventJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dr);
```

and this from SQL Server . 
I've tried to measure the execute time for each of them and the result was : 

 Mongo : 172ms 
SQL : 185ms . 
but as I know the mongoDB should be too much faster than SQL , right !?!

Comment: Why exactly do you think it should be faster?

Comment: why I think mongo should be faster than SQL !?!

Comment: You also should realize that a lot of your overhead is probably not in the data layer, it is probably from the iteration and deserialziation of the data. It is not always the case that MongoDB >> SQL in all use cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoDB isn't necessarily about out-performing SQL server in a simple query like that; The speed advantage comes in when you have ancillary data.  I don't know what your domain looks like, but a common example is a blog.  In a SQL database, you would have a posts table, a comments table, an authors table, etc.  Your query to retrieve all the data required for a single blog post display would either include a few joins or multiple queries (either way will affect the performance a bit).  In a NoSQL database, there could be a single table, Posts.  One query with no joins will pull back all required data.

[Here's a nice blog post talking about the different approaches between a NoSQL type store and a relational store.](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/05/04/document-databases-are-not-relational.aspx)

Comment: nice but if I have 1000000 user , and they pressed reload . what could happen :D !!

Comment: I'm really not certain what you are asking me here; A million users reloading a page at the same time is probably going to fail with either SQL or MongoDB, unless you put a lot of effort into optimization/caching and a really good hardware situation.